# Can I Retrieve Particular Version of Messages with ChangeKey in Graph API?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, delta

Request :  *​​https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userid/mailFolders/inbox/messages*

The Response contains a ChangeKey parameter, Which changes for every modification in messages.

**Is there any way to get a particular version of Mailbox messages with ChangeKey using GraphAPI ?**

Is there any other thing that we can do with the ChangeKey ?

Comment: Why you want to play with changekey? what version you're talking about here? Please be clear. Changekey is a record tracking mechanism used by the respective workload (say mail messages). In case if your intention is to look for sync changes then you need to use the delta or subscription using that you can get related info.

Comment: I am working on delta to get change in messages. I need to get exactly the serious of changes on a single message ( like flagged, liked, categorized, moved ) as a result of which ChangeKey gets modified. Is any other thing we can do with ChangeKey?